# Trying to get or pass Button in/to Custom SurfaceView from the same Layout

Tags: java, android, button, surfaceview

I am creating a small game I have an activity:

**GameActivity.java:**

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    public static Button btnPause;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // requesting to turn the title OFF
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        // making it full screen
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
        btnPause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPause);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "No effect, use the `||` button at top left of screen!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

The layout for above

**game_layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.spaceinvaders.game.GameSurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonPause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/button_pause"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
            </Button>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/health"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ProgressBar
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:minWidth="175dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="@string/ammo"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <ProgressBar
                style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:minWidth="175dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

        <com.spaceinvaders.joystick.JoystickView
            android:id="@+id/joystickView"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonShoot"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:text="X"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And as you might have noticed there is a custom *component*/`SurfaceView`, GameSurfaceView, which looks similar too:

**GameSurfaceView.java**:

```
public class GameSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private GameLoop gameLoop;

    private Bitmap background;
    private Button btnPause;

    public GameSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public GameSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public GameSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {

        btnPause = GameActivity.btnPause;
            //causes NPE 
        btnPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            }
        });

        // adding the callback (this) to the surface holder to intercept events
        getHolder().addCallback(this);

        // create the game loop thread
        gameLoop = new GameLoop(getHolder(), this);

        // make the GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
        setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

Basically I am trying to pass the button `buttonPause` from the `game_layout.xml` to my custom `SurfaceView` `GameSurfaceView` and add a `OnClickListener`; using a static variable However I  keep getting a `NullPointerException`.

I can easily do this in the `GameActivity` class but that becomes a problem for buttons like shoot etc...

So basically my question is how do I pass an `Button`/component from my `GameActivity`/`game_layout` to a `GameSurfaceView` which is contained on `game_layout.xml` class within that activities layout.

I have tried also tried using `findViewById(R.id.buttonPause)` in my `GameSurfaceView` and than adding the `OnClickListener` which produces the same result (NPE).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the GameSurfaceView in the xml, add the view dynamically. This way you can have a constructor in GameSurfaceView that have a Button parameter.

Comment: Hmm thanks for the suggestion I tried it something like this in GameActivity: `FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.layout.game_layout);
fl.addView(new GameSurfaceView(this)); setContentView(fl);` but I get an NPE at: `fl.addView(new GameSurfaceView(this));`

Comment: Is the exception because of init() call? the constructor should be GameSurfaceView(Context context, Button button) and init(Button button). So you findViewById for Pause button and then pass to the constructor.

Comment: I havent even tried passing the button simply just wanted to first get the `SurfaceView` added dynamically to the `GameActivity` `game_layout .xml` but its not going well...

Comment: The error of NPE when dynamicallya diing SurfaceView is happening in GameSurfaceView: `private void init() {
  getHolder().addCallback(this);//NPE HERE }`

Comment: If the surface view is as in your original layout but in your GameSurfaceView without the button code, do you still have this NPE?

Comment: Im not sure I get the question but I cant get the GameSurfaceVew to add dynamically (with or without passing the button).

Comment: If you take out the code for the button in your GameSurfaceView and have your SurfaceView in xml as you had originally. Do you get NPE for getHolder or not?

Comment: Hmm now it seems I get NPE at 
  `FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);` so I guess the Layout isnt being got... (I have added id to the FrameLayout)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29804/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-david-kroukamp)

Answer (score 0):

He can't find the Button in `findViewById()`, because it's called your `SurfaceView`.
Not quite sure if it works, but try to get the `Button` in the `SurfaceView` with:

```
Button btnPause = (Button) getParent().findViewById(R.id.buttonPause);
```

*Edit:*
Oh Sorry, you get a `ViewParent` on `getParent()`..
It will compile like this:

```
View v = (View) getParent();
Button btnPause = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonPause);
```

Comment: Thanks for advice but it wont compile seems my `GameSurfaceView` `getParent()` doesnt have method `findViewById(..)`

Comment: Thanks for edit, I get a NPE at `Button btnPause = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.buttonPause);`